# disable all best_in_place fields with js during AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm using best_in_place 2.1.0 in a rails 3.2 app.

I have a set of best in place fields whose values are dependent on each other. 
Because modifying one changes the values for all of them, I need to disable editing for all of them when an AJAX request is sent from any of them.

If you notice, best in place already disables one field while it's waiting for the AJAX request to finish. I just want to extend this so that it disables all of them.

I tried overriding the onclick

```
$('.best_in_place').bind("onclick", function(e){ 
    e.stopPropogation();
    e.cancelBubble();
    return false; 
});
```

but that didn't work. Sometimes it appeared to be called prior to the creation of the best in place field, but other times it appeared to occur after. Either way, it didn't work for me.

I also thought about using the `"best_in_place:activate"` jQuery trigger, but that is called after `this.activateForm()` in  `BestInPlaceEditor.prototype{.. activate: }` so that doesn't work.

I'm not really sure what to do. Anything that will disable all, or a selection of, best in place fields dynamically will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for a solution for that, I went with adding a class to the element, and canceling events via css:

in the js:

```
$('.best-in-place.parent-setting').on("ajax:success", function(e, t) {
    var enable = $(this).data('bip-value');
    var childrenSettings = $(this).data('children-setting');
    $('.best-in-place.'+childrenSettings).toggleClass('disabled', !enable);
});
```

in the css:

```
.best-in-place.disabled{
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```